# How to assign cognito IAM Role the permissions to perform ListKeys operation for AWS KMS service?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I am using Cognito to get the temporary credentials for authorizing encrypt() operation of the AWS KMS service. In my IAM role policy, I have specified the authorization to encrypt operation on a specific KeyID and  ListKeys operation on all resources. Still I am getting an Access Denied Acception with the error that Cognito is not authorized to perform the operation List Keys. However, when I specify the KeyId in the code and encrypt using it, I am able to do so. 
How is it possible that I am getting to do encrypt operation but not ListKeys ?

Comment: Did you check what's specific action that is denied? You can see it on the error and the cognito assumed role as well.

Comment: Cognito is not authorized to perform the operation List Keys.on resource *